# getting webgl working on ionic crosswalk

Tags: webgl, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

In order to get webGL support on ionic, I added crosswalk

```
npm install ionic -g
ionic start my_app
cd my_app
ionic browser add crosswalk
//add some webGl to index.html
ionic run android
```

but that still didn't allow webgl to run on index.html.  What else do I need to do to get webGL running on ionic Android?

Comment: MonkeyBonkey Did you find a solution for this?? I am looking too?

Comment: never found an answer

Answer (score 0):

Some Android devices is blacklisted on running WEBGL. You need to force it.

Solution: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/webgl-not-working/28274

Refer: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html